# Logstash: How to keep the logstash running continuously on windows

Tags: logstash

Since the logstash process on windows gets closed immediately after the connection to the machine is lost or logged off from the machine, How to keep the logstash process running continuously and in back-end on windows?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Non-Sucking Service Manager](https://nssm.cc/) to install logstash as a windows service. Services can be started at boot and run without an active user login.

Comment: Hi Frank, Thank you for your help. But NSSM is not getting started. It displays a message as:  Unexpected status SERVICE_STOPPED in response to START control. I have specified the logstash start command (logstash agent -f <conf> web) in the Arguments field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows Service Wrapper (https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw).

Simple put the wsw.exe into the logstash bin directory, rename it to logstash.exe and do the same for the configuration xml file. So you have a logstash.exe and logstash.xml file in the bin directory of logstash.

Now you need to adjust the xml file a bit. Mine looks like this (tweak it to your needs):

```
<configuration>
  <id>logstash</id>
  <name>Logstash</name>
  <description>Logstash from elastic.co</description>
  <executable>D:\logstash\bin\logstash.bat</executable>
  <arguments></arguments>
  <serviceaccount>
    <domain>local</domain>
    <user>waffel</user>
    <password>XXX</password>-->
  </serviceaccount>
  <onfailure action="restart" delay="10 sec"/>
  <onfailure action="restart" delay="20 sec"/>
  <onfailure action="none" />
  <resetfailure>1 hour</resetfailure>
  <priority>Normal</priority>
  <stoptimeout>15 sec</stoptimeout>
  <stopparentprocessfirst>false</stopparentprocessfirst>
  <startmode>Automatic</startmode>
  <waithint>15 sec</waithint>
  <sleeptime>1 sec</sleeptime>
  <logpath>D:\logstash\logs</logpath>
  <log mode="append"/>
  <env name="JAVA_HOME" value="D:\jdk8x64" />
</configuration>
```

Then you can simple hit from the cmd (as admin)

```
logstash.exe test
```

Or to install the service

```
logstash.exe install
```

and then you can run from cmd (or service management)

```
logstash.exe start
logstash.exe stop
```

You may whatch the logsfiles for potential errors. For me it works fine with logstash 5.5.1